# No module named 'imagekit' in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-imagekit

i'm running into a very weird error in django rest framework. I tried all the solutions proposed in stackoverflow but nothing.
the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\IVAN.ru\IVAN_backend\backend\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\IVAN.ru\IVAN_backend\backend\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\IVAN.ru\IVAN_backend\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\IVAN.ru\IVAN_backend\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\IVAN.ru\IVAN_backend\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\IVAN.ru\IVAN_backend\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\IVAN.ru\IVAN_backend\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 224, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'imagekit'
```

please notice that i added 'imagekit' to installed apps , I uninstalled and reinstalled everything.
but nothing worked for me. I installed django-imagekit and uninstalled Imagekit.
i tried to replace 'imagekit' with 'Imagekit' .

Comment: try `import imagekit` in your cmd from the same path you run manage.py command

Comment: Also make sure, your virtual env is activated (if you are using)

Answer (score 0):

Install django-imagekit:

```
pip install django-imagekit
```

Use ImageKit in `settings.py` file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  "ImageKit"
  ...
]
```